# How to use one line code to convert the dict to a string?

Tags: python

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b'}

#s = '1|a;2|b'

s = ';'.join([str(k)+'|'+d[k] for k in d])
```

Is there a better way to do this conversion?

Comment: May you clarify what you mean by better if the current one line code works already?

Comment: Better in what way? readability, time, space, coverage of edge cases? What context are you going to use it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd only make two small changes:

1. Use f-strings
2. Use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, which would remove the need to hold all the values in memory prior to joining. It's not really a big deal unless you have thousaaaands of key/value pairs, though.

```
s = ';'.join(f'{k}|{d[k]}' for k in d)
```

Comment: How does this generator work here? I have never used this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "this way"? There's nothing particularly special going on here. I misspoke, this is a *generator expression*, not a generator (like `yield`ing from a function, which is related, but different) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: So the generator expression created by join?

Comment: No. The generator expression is the "f'{k}|{d[k]}' for k in d" being *passed into* `join`. It's just a way to instantiate a `generator` object, which provides your string values on-demand. Please read the PEP I linked, that should give you some more context.